# How bootstrap can load font awsome icons?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, icons, jquery-select2, font-awesome

I am working with bootstrap and select2.
What I am trying to is change text to image in select box.

for instance if selected value of select2 is 'N',
I want to change `data-init-text` to following html.

`<i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-down"></i>`

I will not change the value of input, but only text.

However when I tried with following code, it does not work.

```
var iconicObj = {};
iconicObj.N = 'fa fa-thumbs-o-down';
iconicObj.Y = 'fa fa-thumbs-o-up';

function iconifyCode(id, iconicObj){
    var mother = $('#s2id_2-' + id);
    var target = $(':input[name="' +  id + '"]');
    var value = target.val();
    var icon = iconicObj[value];
//      target.attr('data-init-text', '<i class="' + icon + '"></i>');
    mother.find('.select2-chosen').eq(0).text('').append('<i class="' + icon + '"></i>');
}
```

the `i` tag has inserted but icon does not showed up. 
after loading, it turns like...

```
<span class="select2-chosen" id="select2-chosen-4">
    <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-down">
        ::before
        ::after
    </i>
</span>
```

What `::before` and `::after` does?
I think I could mutate if I know how bootstrap turns a `i` tag into an image.

Thanks.

Comment: Read something about `::before` and `::after`: [this](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/a/after-and-before/) or [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3A%3Abefore).

Comment: Talkning about font-awesome, you may open [CSS source file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/master/css/font-awesome.css) and learn how it uses `:before` to display the value. In short, Font-Awesome is just a special font and a pack of CSS classes which insert characters from this font using `:before`.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev Thanks for summary. Now I got the cause. I also use `smartadmin` plug-in, and it covers another css on it, especially class name with `select`. Now I have 2 `before`s and outer one has empty `content` attribute. Thanks.